# Reshape (grouping or pivoting) pandas dataframe by converting a row into a column

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I want to reshape a dataframe from this shape

```py
Country     subject    2017 2018    Frq  2017 Score     2018 Score
Argentina   subject 1   12   22     100  50.77214238    51.54316539
Argentina   subject 2   68   13     150  66.92805676    67.60645268
```

[image: datafram pic 1]

to this shape

```py
         subject  1                     subject  2                          subject  3…
Country 2017    2018    Frq 2017 Score  2018 Score  2017    2018    Frq 2017 Score  2018 Score  
Argentina   12  22  100 50.77214238 51.54316539 12  22  100 50.77214238 51.54316539 
Australia   68  13  150 66.92805676 67.60645268 68  13  150 66.92805676 67.60645268
```

[image: datafram pic 2]

So Each country has one row. And the values of the column subject are converted into columns

I've tried the following but nothing produced the required results

```py
pd.pivot_table(GCI, index='Country', columns=['subject'],
               values=['2017', '2018'], aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

Also tried:

```py
pivoted_GCI = GCI[['Country']]  #pd.DataFrame()

for key,group_df in GCI.groupby('subject'):
    print("the group for '{}' has {} rows".format(key,len(group_df))) 
    group_df.name = key
    group_df = group_df.drop(['subject'], axis=1)
    display(group_df)
    pivoted_GCI = pd.merge(pivoted_GCI, group_df, on='Country', how='left')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `unstack`

```
s=df.set_index(['Country','subject']).stack().unstack([1,2]).reset_index()
```